# How can I access several specific model elements in a view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2

I have a view that pulls in several partials. Each of these partials needs text that is pulled from a model. Here is the nasty, but working way I am doing it now (this eample is from one partial):

```
 @foreach($posts as $content)
                @if($content['slug']=='infosection1-1')
                    <div class="widget text " id="home-33531_block-221905_text-widget-138178">
                        <h4>{{ $content['title'] }} </h4>
                        <p>{{ $content['body'] }}</p>
                        <p><a class="readmore" href="/local-events/">Read More</a></p>
                        @if(Auth::check())
                            <a href="{{ route('backend.blog.edit', $content['id']) }}">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                            </a>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                @endif
 @endforeach
```

I have tried to access the model elements by using 
`$posts->where('slug','infosection1-1')->getOriginal('title')` (as an example of one text item I need from the model) But, I get an error saying that getOriginal() doesn't exist.

Can anyone give me advice on a new path of logic? I know I should not be putting this logic in a view.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, try this approach:

```
$posts->where('slug','infosection1-1')->first()->title;
```

`$posts` is a collection, so `first()` method will get first found object and `->title` will get the `title` from the object.

Comment: I can only test in a limited way right now  at work. But, that looks like it solved it. I'll select as answer after I can test further. Thanks!